# input validation from read when provided with multiple values

Tags: shell-script

I would like to validate user input from read where user is providing multiple inputs

Example:

```bash
read order_number city cost
```

If user inputs something like `texas 200` from the inputs I should be able to identify order number is missing, when I am trying the below, it always says cost is missing:

```bash
read order_number city cost
echo ""
echo "Job details you have entered are:" $order_number $city $cost
echo ""

if [[ $order_number == '' ]] then
  echo "Order number can't be null"
  exit;
elif [[ $city == '' ]] then
  echo "city can't be null"
  exit;
elif [[ $cost == '' ]] then
  echo "cost can't be null"
  exit;
fi
```

Comment: `texas 200` is assigned to `order_number` and `city` respectively. So I think you will have to validate your input with `regex` (using `grep` maybe).

Comment: For example, if `order_number` must always be a number then you will have to check/validate that your `order_number` is a number and the same for cost, If this one is always `Integer` then validate that this one is a number/Integer. What `shell` are you using, `bash`, `zsh` or any other?

Comment: using bash shell @Edgar Magallon

Comment: And what about `100 2000`? should `city` be considered as `null`? What is your condition for cities? Because it can be applied a pattern to grep only `letters` in city (but I've seen some cities whose can have numbers in their names)

Comment: yes, 
order_number contains Numbers and characters, 

city contains characters and underscore 

cost contains only numbers

Based on the above if the one which is missing needs to be identified and printed acordingly

Comment: What kind of characters? Only alphabet letters? or any character such as `@`, `?`,`*`, etc. ? And about `order_number` does this must start with a number or with a character? Or can start with anyone?

Comment: It is almost impossible for an algorithm to identify WHICH of the three data is missing unless you specify hard criteria that unequivocally tell each from the others. Like cost being a number that may not contain a letter (but think of the engineering / exponent notation), or city being all letters no digits. Any rules for the order_number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the conditions that must be satisfied for each variable you can use this script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

read order_number city cost

#Check if order_number is set 
# Validate order_number starts with any number(s) 
# followed by 0 or more letters and can finish with any letter or number
grep -E --silent "^[0-9]+[A-Za-z]*" <<< "$order_number" || {
   echo "'order_number' cannot be null."
   exit 1
}

#Check if city is set (starts with some letter followed by underscores or more letters )
grep -E --silent "^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_]+$" <<< "$city" || {
   echo "'city' cannot be null."
   exit 1
}


#Check if cost is set (validate is a number)
grep -E --silent "^[0-9]+$" <<< "$cost" || {
   echo "'cost' cannot be null (and must be an Integer)"
   exit 1
}
```

For example, reading this string `"102w1 Texas_ some"` will result in:

```bash
'cost' cannot be null (and must be an Integer)
```

Although `cost` has been read, the `some` value is not a number and therefore it will be consider as `null`.
**If you do really consider the string `some` as not null (for cost variable) then it will be trickier to achiever what you want.**

---

#### Tip

You can test your bash `script` in *non-interactive* way by using this:

```bash
./script < <(echo -n "102w1 Texas_ 30")
```

I save time using the code above when I'm testing that kind of scripts :).

Comment: It is throwing an error for me, I have added an echo statement earlier to the above code and shebang statement #!/usr/bin/ksh

<b>Error details syntax error at line 15 : `<' unexpected </b>

Code is exactly copy pasted from the above

Comment: @HarishPrasad bash and KSH have different syntax/features for some things. Your shebang should be:`#!/usr/bin/bash`. I forgot to add the shebang to the script. Already fixed.